# Why aren't my fonts working?

Tags: html, css, font-face

My fonts work on chrome, opera and safari but not ie or firefox. I'm having trouble understanding @font-face, even after reading the other questions about it.

```
@font-face {
font-family: "TikalSansBlack";
src: url("./fonts/TikalSansBlack.eot?");
src: url("./fonts/TikalSansBlack.woff") format("woff"),
    url("./fonts/TikalSansBlack.ttf")  format("truetype"),
    url("./fonts/TikalSansBlack.svg") format("svg")
    url("./fonts/TikalSansBlack.otf") format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'TikalSansMedium';
    src: url('./fonts/TikalSansMedium.eot?');
    src: url('./fonts/TikalSansMedium.woff') format('woff'),
        url('./fonts/TikalSansMedium.ttf')  format('truetype'),
        url('./fonts/TikalSansMedium.svg') format('svg')
        url('./fonts/TikalSansMedium.otf') format('opentype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'TikalSansThin';
    src: url('./fonts/TikalSansThin.eot?');
    src: url('./fonts/TikalSansThin.woff') format('woff'),
        url('./fonts/TikalSansThin.ttf')  format('truetype'),
        url('./fonts/TikalSansThin.svg') format('svg')
        url('./fonts/TikalSansThin.otf') format('opentype');
}
```

[here's the website I'm working on](http://www.sarahmildenhall.co.nz)

Comment: Please create a reduced test case of the issue on a trusted service such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). I don't trust links to random websites.

Comment: The CSS debugging tool in firefox will tell you everything you need to know

Comment: Mmm isn't the path a little strange " url("./fonts" shouldn't it be " url("../fonts" ?

Comment: `./` means the current directory. It *could* be a typo like you suspect, or just longhand for `url("fonts...`. In any case, this would be obvious when checking out the console - you'd see "file not found" or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma on the last one of every font

```
@font-face {
font-family: "TikalSansBlack";
src: url("./fonts/TikalSansBlack.eot?");
src: url("./fonts/TikalSansBlack.woff") format("woff"),
    url("./fonts/TikalSansBlack.ttf")  format("truetype"),
    url("./fonts/TikalSansBlack.svg") format("svg"),  <<== put comma here
    url("./fonts/TikalSansBlack.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

Also i would be concerned about your file path. If you want to go up a level you need two `.` not one. Maybe this is what's required throughout

```
 url("../fonts/TikalSansBlack.otf")
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thank you, it works fine on all browsers now

Comment: @Vector `./` means 'starting from the current folder' (`fonts/` and `./fonts/` are the same for e.g.). It's different than `/` because this one points to 'starting from domain root' and than `../` which is 'one folder above the current one'

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if that doesn't work I would put all of the sources on one line and if that doesn't work then remove the format attribute. (The fix below adds a comma you missed after the .svg which is an issue on all 3 of the @font-face).

```
  @font-face {
        font-family: 'TikalSansThin';
        src: url('./fonts/TikalSansThin.eot?');
        src: url('./fonts/TikalSansThin.woff') format('woff'),
            url('./fonts/TikalSansThin.ttf')  format('truetype'),
            url('./fonts/TikalSansThin.svg') format('svg'),
            url('./fonts/TikalSansThin.otf') format('opentype');
    }
```